# Escape/Return a function from another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have multiple task functions calling validate() that need to return/escape the main function if there is a validation error. Is it possible to do something like this with typescript / javascript? (I'm working in a node environment)

```
cont validate = () => {
   //validation etc...
   //if validation error
  // return & request mainFunction() to also return
}

const taskOne = () => {
   validate() //some validation error happened when this got called..
}

const taskTwo = () => {
   validate()
}

const mainFunction = () => {
    taskOne();
    taskTwo(); //will not run because taskOne requested return
}

mainFunction();
```

I want to avoid creating an **if** check after each task is executed in case I want to scale up my code with more task calling the validate function. How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Throw errors on validation failure and catch them?

Comment: I don't want the application to stop as it is an ongoing watcher and the validation shall reject and create a bad file. Rather I want it to continue by restarting the mainFunction after the user triggers a save event on the file.

Comment: You need to provide more context. What are you doing with the returned values? preferably, some working code. As it stands this does not seem like a good question.

Answer (score 1):

You could return a boolean value and chain the validations.

```
const validate = (prop) => {
   // validation etc...
   // if validation error
   //     return false & request mainFunction() to also return
   return true;
}

const taskOne = () => validate(one);
const taskTwo = () => validate(two);

const mainFunction = () => taskOne() && taskTwo() && taskThree() /* && ... */;

mainFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I can't use it in my code though cause I'm assigning variables and reusing them in certain task. e.g. let taskOne = taskOne(); let taskTwo = taskTwo(taskOne);

Comment: maybe you add an example what you like to doe withg the return value and how they are connected for an incremented check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple try/catch block, and have the validation function throw an error when the validation fails.

```
const validate = () => {
  if(validationSucceeds) {
    return true;
  } else {
    throw 'error message';
  }
}

const taskOne = () => {
   validate() //some validation error happened when this got called..
}

const taskTwo = () => {
   validate()
}

const mainFunction = () => {
    try {
      taskOne();
      taskTwo(); //will not run because taskOne requested return
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
}

mainFunction();
```